# Creating a view that can be called from any database but runs against local tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

We create databases for each of our clients so that their data is segregated.  For tables that are shared (e.g. product names), we use synonyms to a common database.  For stored procedures that are common, we create them in the master database and mark them as system procedures so that they'll run in the customer database context.  But for views, we're stuck.  A view set as a synonym will not run in the local database and we can't find anything comparable to the system procedure for a view.

So, how do we create a common view that when run, will run in the context of the local customer database?

Comment: The specific answer to your question is probably table valued functions.  However, I would recommend having an "app" database along with the "data" database and use three-part naming throughout the application.  Seems much safer.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the "app" database?

Comment: There are Tools like SSDT which allow you to "compare and update or create" database from a database definition project (a sample virtual database). Maybe it is safer to use this kind of thing to update all your database by creating the view (and the other stuff by the way) on each database. It will also allow you to version your database with your app which could be a good thing.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?   The reason could help to suggest a workaround, because the answer is you cannot " create a common view that when run, will run in the context of the local customer database".

Comment: We have about 40 customer databases.  If views are kept at the customer level, it is decidedly more complex if we need to make a change.  But if all databases ran the same view with their local data, it would make it much easier to maintain and ensure that none of the databases gets out of synch.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do.   Create a script (or optionally a proc) that uses dynamic SQL to create the view in every database in a list that you either supply at run-time or keep in a table.

Then when you want to make a change to the view for every customer, just change the script and run it.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the solution for this.  It just seems so "10 years ago".  I was hoping for something more dynamic that wouldn't require scripting.